# ConnectionString in SharePoint feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, 2016

I have issue with my connectionstring:

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="prod" connectionString="YourConnectionString"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

EventReceiverClass.cs

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["prod"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

and I got error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' on it.
I tested it on a simple console app and it works as expected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the connectionstring in web.config of your SharePoint web application.

[image]

[image]